# Child_process not capturing binary file output?

Tags: c, node.js, electron

I am using the npm library 'child_process' in an electron project to capture the stream of standard output from a C program with spawn. However, when I attempt to log the output from 'printf' or 'fprintf' captured by child.stdout.on('data'), nothing shows up. This is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[256];
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "echo %d\n", i);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buffer);
        system(buffer);
        system("sleep 1");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that my javascript is correct because the line echo'ed by the system call is captured, and I have tested it with similar loops in a ruby script and a bash script and they have worked just fine.

When I run the binary file in a terminal shell everything outputs just fine, but when I try to capture all three outputs (first line should be "echo 0 \n echo 0 \n 0") with child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {...}); the only thing I get back is, like I said, the "0" from the system call. I am at a loss for the solution.

It might be notable that when I run this program in terminal, I can't use ^C to terminate it, as it is just picked up by stdin and carried up the screen with the output.

Here is my javascript if necessary:

```
const { spawn }= require('child_process');
let test;

// Invoked by a button that when clicked calls ipcRenderer.send('test');
ipcMain.on('test', (event, ...args) => {
  test = spawn('./a.out', []);
  test.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try calling `fflush(stdout);` or disabling stdout buffering in your C program?

Comment: @mscdex That did the trick. Do you know the logic behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf()`/`fprintf()` buffers its output by default. You can either manually call `fflush(stdout);` after your calls to `fprintf()` to force the buffered output to stdout *or* you can disable buffering entirely with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` (this must be done once and *before* any output to stdout).